# passing a parameter to the root of a nav controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am initializing a navigation controller and setting the root view controller. Before presenting the controller, I set a variable. However, when the new view is loading, the variable is null. What am I doing wrong?

```
NSString *email = jsonDict[@"email"];

        EmailPopUpViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EmailPopUp"];

        CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        CGFloat xcoord = (screenHeight - 900) / 2;
        CGFloat ycoord = (screenWidth - 640) / 2;

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
        controller.emailURL = email;
        NSLog(@"email: %@", email);

        navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        navController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(xcoord, ycoord, 640, 900);
        [self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: have you set property to **nonatomic** and **strong** of `emailURL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally set the property of emailURL to weak... changing it to strong solved the issue